# What meaning bears here the word "tickets"?

Tags: word-meaning

Here is the context:

Understanding SEO basics can go a long way toward successful collaboration and SEO performance. As a developer, here's what you need to know.

You know the struggle… you just need these **four or five tickets** taken care of and it would mean so much to your SEO goals for the month.

Answer (score 1):

In software development, a ticket is a bug, issue or problem with a piece of software that needs fixing or putting right. Software companies usually have a 'ticket tracking system' so that these can be logged, tracked, and (hopefully) resolved.

> An issue tracking system is similar to a "bugtracker", and often, a
> software company will sell both, and some bugtrackers are capable of
> being used as an issue tracking system, and vice versa. Consistent use
> of an issue or bug tracking system is considered one of the "hallmarks
> of a good software team".[3] A ticket element, within an issue
> tracking system, is a running report on a particular problem, its
> status, and other relevant data. They are commonly created in a help
> desk or call center environment and almost always have a unique
> reference number, also known as a case, issue or call log number which
> is used to allow the user or help staff to quickly locate, add to or
> communicate the status of the user's issue or request.

[Issue tracking system (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system#:%7E:text=A%20ticket%20element%2C%20within%20an,status%2C%20and%20other%20relevant%20data.)